# Proving a polynomial irreducible over finite field

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I prove that $x^p-x+a$ is irreducible in a field of $p$ elements when $a\neq 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81583/how-do-i-prove-that-xp-xa-is-irreducible-in-a-field-of-p-elements-when-a)

How to prove that $x^p - x - 1$ is irreducible over $F_{p}[x]$. 
I thought proving that this polynomial has no roots over $F_p$ but that is not enough to irreducibility.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136164/problem-in-jacobsons-basic-algebra-vol-i/136184#136184

Comment: Keywords "Artin-Schreier polynomial"

Comment: I hate to spoil your fun, but this is an [exact duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a splitting field $K$, if $\alpha\in K$ is a root, then $(\alpha+1)^p= \alpha^p+1$ implies that $\alpha+1$ is a root as well. We conclude that the cyclic group of order $p$ operates on the roots (by addition of multiples of $1$), and necessarily does so transitively (as there are $p$ roots). A non-trivial factor of the polynomial would correspond to a non-trivial subgroup, which does not exist.

Comment: Can you explain the last line "A non-trivial factor of the polynomial would correspond to a non-trivial subgroup, which does not exist."

Comment: Maybe a different view helps): If we factor $X^p-X-1=f(X)g(X)$ non-trivially, then the Galois group leaves $f$ and $g$ fixed, hence the cyclic group of order $p$ operates on less than $p$ roots of $f$ and $g$ respectively. Since $p$ is prime, this operation must be trivial. But $\alpha\mapsto\alpha+1$ is definitely not the trivial operation.

Comment: @Mystic: See zyx's or Greg Martin's answer to the duplicate question for an argument. (+1 to Hagen)

Comment: +1 Simple and beautiful. Yet, perhaps the following *more expanded* argument (which already exists in Hagen's answer) could prevent doubt: it's been proved $\,\alpha\,$ is a root $\,\Longrightarrow \alpha+1\,$ is a root. Now, the same argument shows that $$\alpha +1\,\,\text{is a root}\Longrightarrow \,\alpha +1+1=\alpha +2$$ is a root , and etc. One gets that $\,\alpha, \alpha+1,...,\alpha+p-1$ are all different roots of the polynomial...