# Irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb F_5$

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

In my book text of Galois theory:

The polynomial $X^5-X-1$ over $\mathbb Z$. In $\mathbb F_5$ is irreducible.

Could you explain why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of an [Artin-Schreier polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory). You can find general proofs about their irreduciblity in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/184154) and [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136164/184154).