# Irreducibility of $x^5 -x -1$ by reduction mod 5

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Is there a quick way of deducing that $x^5-x-1 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible by reducing it mod 5, other than verifying that it has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and no factorization as the product of a factor of order 2 and a factor of order 3?

Comment: Perhaps not as "quick" as desired, but it must be noted that this is an example of "Artin-Schreier" polynomials $x^p-x+a$ which for $a\not=0$ are always irreducible over $\mathbb F_p$. In particular, one does not try to take advantage of "small numbers", as in the degrees of putative factors. Just that the Galois group of any extension of $\mathbb F_p$ is generated by Frobenius $\beta\rightarrow \beta^p$, and here a root $\beta$ behaves like $\beta^p=\beta-a$. The smallest power that fixes it is $p$-th power, so a root is in $\mathbb F_p$, the fixed field of Frobenius.

Comment: [A collection of proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619) for the irreducibility of polynomials $x^p-x+a$ over $\Bbb{F}_p$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ If it had an irreducible quadratic factor $\rm\:f(x)\:$  then $\rm\:\Bbb F_5[x]/(f(x)) = \Bbb F_5[w] = \Bbb F_{25}\,$ so
$$\rm w^5 = w\!+\!1,\ \ \color{#C00}w = w^{25} = (w^5)^5 = (w\!+\!1)^5 = w^5\! +\! 1^5 = \color{#C00}w\!+\!2\:\Rightarrow\: \color{#C00}0 = 2\:\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$$

**Remark** $\ $ The same proof works generally. Let $\rm\:p\:$ be prime. Working in $\rm \,\Bbb F_p[x]\,$ suppose that $\rm\:g = x^p\! -\!x\! -\! 1\:$ has an irreducible factor $\rm\:f\:$ of degree $\rm\:n< p.\,$ Then in $\rm\:\Bbb F_p[x]/(f) = \Bbb F_p[w] = \Bbb F_{p^n},\:$ $\rm\:w^p = w\!+\!1\:$ so the linear Frobenius map $\rm\:z\to z^p\:$ is just the shift $\rm\:S\!: w\to w\!+\!1,\,$ $\rm\, k\to k\in\Bbb F_p.\:$ Iterated $\rm\:n\:$ times yields $\rm\: w\!+\!n = S^n\, w  = w^{p^n}\! =w,\:$ thus $\rm\: 0 = n < p\:$ in $\rm\,\Bbb F_p,\,$ a contradiction.

Alternatively, equivalently, one can instead  show that $\rm\:gcd(x^p\!-\!x\!-\!1,\,x^{p^n}\!-\!x) = 1.$ For example, see the answer by Thomas Andrews.

Once one learns some Galois theory these and related arguments will become much more intuitive, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4282640/242) for a simple example.

Answer (score 9):

Note that it is easy to see there are no roots in $\mathbb Z_5$: by Fermat's theorem, $x^5 - x - 1$ is always $-1$.

This is called an Artin-Schreier polynomial, and with just a little more insight we can see that it is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_5$.  If $\alpha$ is a particular root in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Z_5$, then all 5 roots are given by $\alpha + k$ for each $k \in \mathbb Z_5$ (think "freshman's dream").

Let $d$ be the degree $[\mathbb Z_5(\alpha) : \mathbb Z_5]$.  As noted by Patrick Da Silva below, we also have $[\mathbb Z_5(\alpha + k) : \mathbb Z_5] = d$.

Since $x^5-x-1$ splits as $$\prod_{k\in \mathbb Z_5} (x-\alpha+k),$$
the irreducible factorization of $x^5-x-1$ consists entirely of polynomials of degree $d$.  Since $d > 1$ as $\alpha \notin \mathbb Z_5$, this forces $d = 5$.

It might be a stretch to say this is faster than direct computation in this tiny case, but I'm guessing it's along the lines you were looking for.

Comment: "But this is impossible since the degree $[\mathbb{Z}_5(\alpha):\mathbb{Z}_5]$ is prime." You are kind of putting the cart before the horse here. How do you know this?

Comment: @jspecter : $x^5-x-1 = (x-\alpha)(x-\alpha+1)(\dots)(x - \alpha+4)$. If $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then $p(x-k)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha+k$. Now $x^5-x-1$ is the product of the minimal polynomials of the roots because its separable ; the fact that the degree is prime gives you the result.

Comment: Thanks for catching this, will fix.

Comment: The usual proof is that if $x^5 - x - 1 = \prod_{k = 0}^{p - 1} (x - \alpha - k)$ has a non-trivial factor of degree $m$ then its coefficient of $x^{m - 1}$ will be in $\mathbb Z_5$ and, writing that out, this will imply that $\alpha \in \mathbb Z_5$, which you know is untrue.

Answer (score 7):

Your polynomial is quite special, so that there are many specific ways to prove its irreducibility, as indicated in other answers. Here is how [Berlekamp's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm), which will detect irreducibilty of general polynomials over finite fields and and leads to a factorisation if they are reducible, applies to this particular case; while not as slick as other approaches it is quite doable by hand.

You first need to check the polynomial $P=X^5-X-1\in\mathbb F_5[X]$ is squarefree by computing the gcd with its formal derivative; the latter is $-1$ in the example, so that's OK.

Next one considers the ring $A=\mathbb F_5[X]/(P)$ as vector space over $\mathbb F_5$, and computes the matrix of the $\mathbb F_5$-linear (thanks to Frobenius) map $f:A\to A$ given by $x\mapsto x^5-x$ on the basis $(1,X,X^2,X^3,X^4)$; in general this would require reducing a certain number of powers of $X$ modulo $P$, but the special form of $P$ allows avoiding that here using $X^{5i}\equiv (X+1)^i\pmod P$ for any $i$, so that the matrix is
$$
  \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&1&1&1\\ 0&0&2&3&4\\ 0&0&0&3&1\\ 0&0&0&0&4\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This matrix clearly has rank $4$ (note the $4\times 4$ triangular minor), so $\dim\ker(f)=1$. This proves that $P$ is irreducible, since if $P$ were reducible, then $A$ would be a product of more than one ring (by the Chinese remainder theorem and the fact that $P$ is squarefree) each of which would contain a copy of $\mathbb F_5$, and the product of these copies would form a subspace of dimension${}>1$ contained in the kernel of $f$, and this is impossible.

**Added.** To illustrate the reducible case, consider the following related question. It is fairly easy to see that $X^p-X-1\in\mathbb F_p$ will be irreducible for any prime $p$ (and even $X^p-X-a$ for any $a\in\mathbb F_p^\times$ will be irreducible), as several answers indicate; the computation above will give a truncated Pascal triangle matrix with a nonzero $(p-1)\times(p-1)$ minor, and therefore still $\dim\ker(f)=1$. So one might think that maybe even $X^q-X-1\in\mathbb F_q$ would be irreducible for any *prime power* $q$.

However, if one computes the matrix of $f: x\mapsto x^4-x$ in $A=\mathbb F_4[X]/(X^4+X+1)$ one finds
$$
  \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&1&1\\ 0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0\\ \end{pmatrix}
  \in M_4(\mathbb F_4)
$$
whose rank is only $2$, so this shows that $X^4+X+1$ is reducible in $\mathbb F_4[X]$ (if it were irreducible then $A$ would be a field, and $\ker f=\mathbb F_4$, of dimension $1$). Indeed one can see similarly that $X^q-X-1\in\mathbb F_q$ is *always reducible* when $q$ is a prime power but not a prime.

To concretely find a factorisation of $P=X^4-X-1\in\mathbb F_4$, one lets $Q\in\mathbb F_4[X]$ run through representatives of a coset of $\mathbb F_4$ in $\ker f$ that does not contain $0$, and computes $\gcd(P,Q)$ for all of them, which should reveal nontrivial factors of $P$. One can take that coset to be $\{\,X^2+X+c\mid c\in\mathbb F_4\,\}$, and one finds nontrivial factors (indeed the representative $Q$ itself) for $c=\alpha$ (a root of $X^2+X+1$ in $\mathbb F_4$) and for $c=\alpha+1$; one may check that in fact $X^4+X+1=(X^2+X+\alpha)(X^2+X+\alpha+1)$ in $\mathbb F_4[X]$.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to prove that $h(x)=x^5-x-1$ is relatively prime to $x^{25}-x$, since that polynomial is the product of all monic primes in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ of degree $1$ and $2$.

Or, alternatively, show that $h(x)$ is a factor of $\frac{x^{5^5}-x}{x^5-x}$.

In general, $x^{p^n}-x$ is the product of all monic primes in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ whose degree divides $n$.

It's actually not hard to show that, in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$, $x^{p^p}-x$ is divisible by $h(x)$, and that no prior $x^{p^n}-x$ is divisible by $h(x)$.

Essentially, you prove inductively that $x^{p^n}-x \equiv n \pmod{h(x)}$, and hence that $x^{p^p}-x$ is divisible by $h(x)$, and $x^{p^n}-x$ and $h(x)$ are relatively prime for $1\leq n<p$.

So let's prove my claim.

Clearly, $n=1$ is true, since $x^p-x = h(x)+1\equiv 1 \pmod {h(x)}$

Assume that $x^{p^n}-x \equiv n \pmod {h(x)}$.

Then $x^{p^n} \equiv x+n \pmod {h(x)}$.

Raise both sides to the $p$, and you get:

$$x^{p^{n+1}} \equiv (x+n)^p = x^p + n^p \equiv x+1+n = x+(n+1)\pmod {h(x)}$$

Subtract $x$ from both sides and you get the result required.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more general claim. We claim that given any $a\neq 0 \in F$ where $F = \Bbb{Z}_5$, the polynomial $$f(x) = x^5 - x- a\in F[x]$$ is irreducible. Now the condition $a \neq 0$ shows that this polynomial has no roots in $F$. Then as Erick Wong notes above such a polynomial by the schoolboy binomial theorem will have all its roots in an extension as long as it has at least one of them.

Now we claim that $f(x)$ is actually irreducible over $F$. Suppose it is not so that we can write $f =gh$ for some polynomials $g$ and $h$ with $\deg g, \deg h \geq 2$. Neither of them can have degree 1 because otherwise this would contradict $f(x)$ having no roots in $F$. Then $F[x]/(g)$ and $F[x]/(h)$ are extensions of $F$ that have at least one root of $f$ in them. By the note above, $F[x]/(g)$ and $F[x]/(h)$ contain all the roots of $f$. It is easy to see that $F[x]/(g)$ and $F[x]/(h)$ are splitting fields for $f$. But then any two splitting fields are isomorphic so that in particular $[F[x]/(g) : F]  = [F[x]/(h) : F]$.

But then this means that $\deg f$ is twice the degree of $g$ (or $h$ for that matter) which is a contradiction because $5$ is an odd number and hence is not divisibly by $2$. Hence $f$ is irreducible over $F$.

$\hspace{6in} \square$

Comment: The formulation of your proof assumes implicitly ("extension", "splitting field") that $g$ and $h$ are irreducible polynomials. However on the sole assumption that $f$ is reducible, one cannot assume this. It can be deduced in this case by degree consideration (since $\deg f=5$ cannot be sum of more than two numbers${}>1$), but this should be said more clearly. Also note that for $x^p-x-a$ over $\mathbb F_p$, where the result is still true (cf. other answers), such a degree argument would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p$ is a prime and  $$f(x):=x^p-x-1=f_1(x)f_2(x)\ldots f_n(x)$$ where $f_i(x)$ is irreducible for each $i$. Suppose $a$ is a root of $f(x)$, wlog assume $f_1(a)=0$. Now note that for each $1\leq j\leq (p-1),$ $f(a+j)=(a^p+j^p)-(a+j)-1=0$, so there is a $f_j\ne f_1$ such that $f_j(a+j)=0$. So we have $f_j(a+j)=f_1(a)$ which implies $\deg(f_j)=\deg(f_1)$ for all $j$. So $\deg(f)=n.\deg(f_1)=p$ and this implies $n=1$ or $p$. If $n=p$ then all the roots are in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ but this would imply $0$ is a root of $f(x)$ ( because of the fact: $a$ is a root implies $a+j$ is a root), which is not true. Hence $n=1$ and so $f(x)$ is irreducible.