# How to factor a polynomial modulo p?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, factoring

Is there a general strategy to factoring a polynomial modulo p? I've looked on Google but I've had a hard time finding anything that specifically outlines an approach that I can understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is for instance [Berlekamp's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm), which I discussed in some detail in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/175253/18880).

Comment: This algorithm only works for squarefree polynomials, right? Is there a general algorithm?

Comment: @Anakhand The method I described starts by _checking_ that the polynomial$~P$ is squarefree, by computing $\gcd(P,P')$. If the test fails, you've found a strict divisor of $P$. So you can apply induction on the degree to show there is a method to factor both that divisor and the quotient of $P$ by it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there  is. Refer to these links, there's a clear description on how modulo primes determine the factorization of polynomials.

[Elementary properties of polynomials](http://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/intpoly.pdf)

[Integer Polynomials](http://www.yimin-ge.com/doc/cyclotomic_polynomials.pdf)

Comment: Excuse me, but does anything in those texts discuss actually factoring polynomials over a field $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$? I thought the question was about that.