# $x^p-x-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra

For any prime  p, prove  that  $x^p-x-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$[x].

(In a field of characteristic p this is true).

I asummed exist root in $\mathbb{Q}$, let's call $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then following that  $\frac{\alpha ^p}{\beta ^p} - \frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1  = 0$ and then $\alpha ^p - \alpha \beta ^{p-1} - \beta ^p =0$. So $\alpha ^p = -\beta^p (1 + \alpha \beta ^{-1})$. But this only proves that $x^p -x -1$ don't have rational roots.

Comment: **A polynomial can be reducible without having a root**. For example, the polynomial $x^4+4$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ since
$$x^4+4=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$$
but it has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The polynomial does not have any rational root, your argument will work because you can add an hypothesis on $\gcd(\alpha,\beta)=1$ and you finish by the same equation but it's not pssible as $\alpha$ will divide $\beta^p$ and hence $\alpha=1$, But this is far to be a proof of irreductibility

Comment: How about (Frank)  Eisenstein's criterionhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion  ?

Comment: What @Zev said holds obviously for degree 3 and higher.

Comment: What Zev says. And this polynomial is not irreducible in all fields of characteristic $p$. For example it has $p$ zeros in the field of $p^p$ elements and factors into linear factors over that field.

Answer (score 3):

For instance we have $x^p-x-1$ is irreducible in $F_p$ which implies that the same polynomial is irreducible over the field of rationals, the converse is not correct we can find polynomial which are irreducible in the field of rationals and reducible for any prime $p$.

Assume that $P=x^p-x-1$ is reducible over rational numbers and write:
$$P=QR$$
so in $F_p$ we have $\overline{P}=\overline Q\overline R$ which is a factorization if $F_p$ and this is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't know why are you changing the polynomial but note that the same thing holds for every polynomial of the form $x^p-x+a$ where $a\neq 0$

Comment: You should explain why $x^p-x-1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb F_p$, most readers will not find this obvious.

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81583/how-do-i-prove-that-xp-xa-is-irreducible-in-a-field-with-p-elements-when and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450608/show-that-fx-xp-x-1-in-bbbf-px-is-irreducible-over-bbbf-p-fo answers that.

Comment: Is this a valid argument? This means that every irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb F_p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ !

Comment: @Elaqqad this does not work, for example $(1+px)(x^p-x-1)$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q$ but not over $\mathbb F_p$ .