# Irreducible polynomial in $Z[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $f(x)=x^p-x+k$ is irreducible in $Z[X]$,where $p$ is a prime and $k$ is an integer not divisible by $p$.

I think I solved it, but it seems very easy,so the proof could be incorrect.
Proof:
Let $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ and let $\alpha$ be root of $g$,now reduce $f$ modulo $p$ and we get $f^{*}=k$ and $g^{*}$ divides $f^{*}$,therefore $g=pq(x)+k_1$,where $k_1$ is not divisible by $p$ and $q$ is with integer coefficients,hence because $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer $p$ must divide $k_1$,which is a contradiction.

Comment: Do the same as [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241177/xp-x-1-is-irreducible-over-mathbbqx), which is for $k=-1$.

Comment: My proof is the same as the one there.

Comment: Then everything is fine.

Comment: @KristiyanVasilev: It is *not* true that when you reduce $X^p - X$ modulo $p$ you get $0$; you still get $X^p - X$. What you get, though, is that the *polynomial function* $x^p-x : \Bbb F_p \to \Bbb F_p$ is $0$, indeed, but do not mistake a polynomial for its associated polynomial function!

Comment: @DietrichBurde: That proof does not explain why $x^p-x-1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb F_p$, and I don't find this statement obvious.

Comment: @KristiyanVasilev: Who says that $f$, $g$ or $h$ must have a root in $\Bbb Z$ or in $\Bbb F_p$?

Comment: @AlexM. Indeed, that is not obvious, but an even more frequent [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450608/show-that-fx-xp-x-1-in-bbbf-px-is-irreducible-over-bbbf-p-fo).

Comment: @AlexM: Can you give a solution to the problem?

Comment: @KristiyanVasilev: By intelligently adapting the answers by **Elaqqad** and **cat** in the links given by **Dietrich Burde**, you should be able to solve the problem by yourself. If you don't make it, signal it to me in a comment.