# Show that $X^p-X-1\in \mathbb Q[X]$ is irreducible.

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How can I show that $X^p-X-1\in \mathbb Q[X]$ is irreducible ? I tried reduction modulo $p$, but doesn't work, even some normal variable changing as $X\longmapsto X+1$ or $X\longmapsto X-1$, but nothing. Any idea ?

Comment: Reduction mod $p$ does work. But you also need [this perfectly fitting result](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $f(x) = x^p -x -1 \in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_p$ for every $p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450608/show-that-fx-xp-x-1-in-bbbf-px-is-irreducible-over-bbbf-p-fo)