# $x^p-x+a$ irreducible for nonzero $a\in K$ a field of characteristic $p$ prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, positive-characteristic

Is it true that $f(x)=x^p-x+a\in K[x]$ is irreducible for nonzero $a\in K$ a field of characteristic $p$ prime?

I've seen variants of this question around, but they don't seem to answer the question as worded.  (It's possible I have not searched well enough or misunderstood the techniques already given)

---

I almost understand the case for **finite** fields:

If $p=2$,  then to show irreducibility we need only show that it has no roots.

For $p>2$, I can show that it's separable since the formal derivative is $-1$. Separability also follows from $f(\alpha)=0\Rightarrow f(\alpha+1)=0$.  This also shows that if $\alpha$ were a root in $\mathbb{F}_p$ then $0$ would be a root, a contradiction since we assumed $a\neq 0$; hence the polynomial has no roots in the prime subfield of $K$.  [...] But then?  Arguments I have seen seem to use the additional fact that $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}_p$.

---

I imagine it will come down to some kind of argument with coefficients (depending on roots, maybe using elementary symmetric polynomials) but other nifty ways I'm not seeing also appreciated.

Comment: Some of the arguments given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619) explain the relation between the coefficient of next to highest degree term of a factor and a zero. The relation is linear with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $K$ be any field of characteristic $p$ with more than $p$ elements. Then $x^p-x$ has only the $p$ elements of the prime field as roots. Pick $b$ not in the prime field and let $a=-(b^p-b)$. Then $x^p-x+a$ has $b$ as root (and $b+k$ for $k$ in the prime field).

Comment: This is very helpful, hands on and it shows exactly where its reducible.

Answer (score 4):

No, in general it is not true that the Artin-Schreier polynomial $x^p-x+\alpha$ is irreducible in any field of characteristic $p$. For instance, if $K$ is algebraically closed, the polynomial is obviously never irreducible.

Comment: And here I was thinking the polynomial was just some random pick.

Answer (score 3):

Or, just take $K=\mathbb Z_p[y]/\langle y^p-y+1\rangle$ for the most basic counterexample, since $y^p-y+1$ is prime in $\mathbb Z_p[y]$. Then But $x^p-x+1$ has a root $y$ in $K$.