# Why is $X^5-6X+3$ irreducible?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

In my math course, it is written that since over $\mathbb{F}_5[X]$, $P$ has no root in $\mathbb{F}_{25}$, it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ by Gauss Lemma.

I don't really understand…

If we prove that $P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, then Gauss proves it is over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, but I don't understand what $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ is doing there…

The exact question was :" Find a prime $p$ such that the reduction of $P(X)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ has no root in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, then show that $P$ is irreducible"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So Gauss' lemma states that irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$ implies irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$; so it suffices to show that $f = x^5 -6x + 3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. Now irreducibility in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ (provided that $p$ does not divide the leading coefficient of $f$) implies irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$. So if $f$ was *reducible*, what are the possible factorizations? Well since $\mathbb{F}_{5}[x]$ admits unique factorization, there are the following options:

1. $f$ is the product of 5 linear factors.
2. $f$ is the product of 3 linear factors and an irreducible quadratic
3. $f$ is the product of 2 linear factors and an irreducible cubic.
4. $f$ is the product of a single linear factor and an irreducible quartic.
5. $f$ is the product of a single linear factor and two irreducible quadratics.
6. $f$ is the product of a single irreducible quadratic and a single irreducible cubic.

Checking that $f$ has no root in $\mathbb{F}_{5}$ rules out options 1-5. Now since $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ is the splitting field extension for all quadratics over $\mathbb{F}_{5}$, if $f$ possessed an irreducible quadratic in its factorization then $f$ would have a root in $\mathbb{F}_{25}$.

Comment: Ok, I understand better now, but why "$\mathbb{F}_{25}$ is the splitting field extension for all quadratics over $\mathbb{F}_{5}$"?

Comment: Ahah I think I understood. If there is an irreductible quadradic, then its splitting field has $5^2=25$ elements, hence is $\mathbb{F}_{25}$!

Comment: Looks like you got it.

Answer (score 4):

$x^5-6x+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$ because it is an [Artin–Schreier polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory), of the form $x^p-x+\alpha$ for $p=5$: since such polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$, it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, too.

---

$x^5-x+3$ has no root in $\mathbb{F}_5$ or $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ because the $\gcd$ between $x^{5^2}-x$ and $x^5-x+3$ is $1$: by assuming $x^5=x-3$ it follows that $x^{5^2}=(x-3)^{5}=x^5-3=x-6$ hence $x^{5^2}-x = -1$.
It follows that $x^5-x+3$ factors over $\mathbb{F}_5$ as the product of irreducible polynomials with degree $\geq 3$ and the conclusion is the same as before: $x^5-x+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$, hence it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Sure, but I don't think we are supposed to know that… The previous question was: "Find a prime $p$ such that the reduction of $P(X)$ over $F_p[X]$ has no root in $F_{p^2}$"

Comment: @Labo: the splitting field of $x^5-x+3$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$ is $\mathbb{F}_{5^5}$: you may easily prove that (that is the same as proving the mentioned lemma: if someone does not teach you something, it does not imply you cannot learn it on your own) and deduce that such polynomial has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_{5^2}$.

Comment: @Labo: anyway, I have modified my answer including the approach it was probably meant by the problem poser.

Comment: Thanks! But why "It follows that $x^5-x+3$ factors over $\mathbb{F}_5$ as the product of irreducible polynomials with degree $\geq 3$"?  Does the 3 come from the 2 of $p^2$?

Comment: @Labo: there cannot be irreducible factors with degree $1$ or $2$ because $x^5-x+3$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_5$ or $\mathbb{F}_{5^2}$, hence the degree of every irreducible factor is $\geq 3$, i.e. there is a single irreducible factor with degree $5$.

Comment: With a view of making the site as self-contained as possible I will comment that we have collected [many proofs](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619) for the irreducibility of Artin-Schreier polynomials in the case of a prime field. A nice observation that it applies here.