# The polynomial $f(x) = 2x^6 + 6x^5 + 4x^4 + 5x^3 + 3x +1 $ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How can I prove that the polynomial $f(x) = 2x^6 + 6x^5 + 4x^4 + 5x^3 + 3x +1 $ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: For anyone likewise tempted: I've tried several constants to apply Eisenstein's criterion (replacing x with x+1, x+2, x+3). None of these worked.

Comment: It cannot be written as linear factors as only divisors of $1$ are $1$,$-1$ and none of $f(1)$ or $f(-1)$ are zero.next we have to check for quadratic,cubi,biquadratic.

Comment: Probably a bit overkill but I think Corollary 2 in paper [ON AN IRREDUCIBILITY THEOREM OF A. COHN](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v33/cjm1981v33.1055-1059.pdf) seems to work for $b=14$, but requires to check that $f(14)=18453443$ is a prime :)

Comment: @Sil You should post that as an answer if no lesser kill comes up ;-) That's usually referred to as [Cohn's irreducibility criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion).

Comment: @dxiv Ok I did, I wasn't sure at first and have to rush to work, hopefuly it is alright now.

Comment: The smallest prime (except 2) mod which the polynomial is irreducible, is 29.

Comment: @DietrichBurde No. What you factorized is $x^3+1$, what we need is $x^3+x+1$...

Comment: Yes, I know. I forgot the term $3x$.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Cohn's irreducibility criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion) (see also Corollary 1 in article [ON AN IRREDUCIBILITY THEOREM OF A. COHN](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v33/cjm1981v33.1055-1059.pdf)) if we find integer $b\geq 2$ such that $0 \leq a_k \leq b-1$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k b^k$ is a prime, then $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k x^k$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

In this case $b=14$ satisfies conditions of the criterion since $f(14)=18453443$ is a prime and so the $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Not as pretty as Eisenstein but works.

Comment: Otherwise put, the number made out of the coefficients is a prime in base $14\,$: $2645031_{14}=18453443$.

Comment: This is a nice argument. I just wonder what technology makes it easier to show that $f(14)$ is a prime number in comparison to factoring the polynomial modulo small primes :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That was bothering me as well, it seems that is an issue with this method in general...

Answer (score 4):

Let $f = 2x^6 + 6x^5 + 4x^4 + 5x^3 + 3x +1$ and suppose $f = gh$ for some $g,h$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $g,h \notin \{\pm 1\}$.

Without loss of generality, we can assume the leading coefficients of $g,h$ are both positive.

It follows that one of $g,h$ is monic, and the other has leading coefficient $2$.

Also, the constant terms of $g,h$ are either both $1$ or both $-1$.

Since $f$ has no rational roots, it follows that either $g,h$ are both degree $3$, or else one is quadratic, and the other degree $4$.

Then

\begin{align*}
2x^6 + 6x^5 + 4x^4 + 5x^3 + 3x +1&= gh\;\text{in}\;\mathbb{Z}[x]\\[4pt]
\implies\;x^3 + x + 1&= gh\;\text{in}\;\mathbb{Z_2}[x]
\end{align*}

Note that $x^3+x+1$ has no root in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, hence, since it's cubic, it's irreducible in $\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$.

Then since $x^3 + x + 1= gh\;\text{in}\;\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$, it follows that in $\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$, one of $g,h$ equals $1$, and the other is equal to $x^3+x+1$.

Without loss of generality, assume $g = x^3 + x + 1\;\text{in}\;\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$.

Then in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we must have $\text{deg}(g) \ge 3$, hence either $\text{deg}(g)=3$ or $\text{deg}(g)=4$.

Suppose $\text{deg}(g)=4$.

Since $g = x^3 + x + 1\;\text{in}\;\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$, in $\;\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the leading coefficient of $g$ (i..e., the coefficient of $x^4$) must be even, hence must be $2$, and the coefficient of the $x^3$ term must be odd. Applying Vieta's formula for the sum of the roots, the sum of the roots of $g$ has a denominator of $2$ and an odd numerator, hence is not an integer. But since $g$ has leading coefficient $2$, $h$ must be monic, hence the sum of the roots of $h$ *is* an integer. But then the sum of the roots of $g$ plus the sum of the roots of $h$ is not an integer, contradiction, since the sum of the roots of $f$ is $-3$.

Thus, we must have $\text{deg}(g)=3$.

Since $g$ is cubic and $g = x^3 + x + 1\;\text{in}\;\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$, it follows that
$g$ is monic, and

$$g = x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$$

where $a_2,a_1,a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, with $a_2$ even, and $a_1,a_0$ odd.

Moreover, as previously, noted, either $a_0=1$ or $a_0 = -1$.

Since $g$ is cubic, so is $h$, and since $g$ is monic, the leading coefficient of $h$ is $2$.

Also, the constant terms of $g,h$ are equal, so the constant term of $h$ is $a_0$.

Since $h = 1\;\text{in}\;\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$, it follows that

$$h = 2x^3 + b_2x^2 + b_1x + a_0$$

where $b_2,b_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, with $b_2,b_1$ even.

Expanding the product

$$(x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0)(2x^3 + b_2x^2 + b_1x + a_0)$$

and equating the coefficients to the corresponding coefficients of $f$, we get the equations

\begin{align*}
a_0(a_1 + b_1) &= 3\tag{eq1}\\[4pt]
a_0(a_2 + b_2) + a_1b_1 &=0\tag{eq2}\\[4pt]
3a_0 + a_1b_2 + a_2b_1 &= 5\tag{eq3}\\[4pt]
2a_1 + b_1 + a_2b_2 &=4\tag{eq4}\\[4pt]
2a_2 + b_2 &=6\tag{eq5}\\[12pt]
\text{Using $(\text{eq}5),$}\;\,2a_2 + b_2 &=6\\[4pt]
\implies\;0 + b_2 &= 2\pmod 4
&&\text{[since $a_2$ is even]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; b_2 &\equiv 2 \pmod 4\\[12pt]
\text{Using $(\text{eq}4),$}\;\,2a_1 + b_1 + a_2b_2 &=4\\[4pt]
\implies\; 2 + b_1 + 0 &\equiv 0 \pmod 4
&&\text{[since $a_1$ is odd,}\\[-1pt] 
&&&\;\text{and $a_2,b_2$ are even]}\\[-1pt]
\implies\; b_1 &\equiv 2 \pmod 4\\[12pt]
\text{Using $(\text{eq}2),$}\;\,a_0(a_2 + b_2) + a_1b_1 &=0\\[4pt]
\implies\; a_0(a_2 + 2) + 2 &\equiv 0 \pmod 4
&&\text{[since $a_1$ is odd,}\\[-1pt]
&&&\;\text{and $b_2 \equiv 2\,(\text{mod}\;4)$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; a_2 &\equiv 0 \pmod 4
&&\text{[since $a_0$ is odd,}\\[-1pt]
&&&\;\text{and $a_2$ is even]}\\[4pt]
\text{Using $(\text{eq}3),$}\;\,3a_0 + a_1b_2 + a_2b_1 &= 5\\[4pt]
\implies\; 3a_0 + 2 + 0 &\equiv 5 \pmod 4
&&\text{[since $a_1$ is odd,}\\[-1pt]
&&&\;\text{$b_2 \equiv 2\,(\text{mod}\;4)$,}\\[-1pt] 
&&&\;\text{and $a_2,b_1$ are even]}\\[-1pt]
\implies\; a_0 &\equiv 1 \pmod 4\\[4pt]
\implies\; a_0 &= 1
&&\text{[since $a_0 \in \{\pm 1\}$]}\\[12pt]
\text{Using $(\text{eq}1),$}\;\,a_0(a_1 + b_1) &= 3\\[4pt]
\implies\;  a_1 + b_1 &= 3
&&\text{[since $a_0=1$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;  a_1 + 2 &\equiv 3 \pmod 4 
&&\text{[since $b_1 \equiv 2\,(\text{mod}\;4)$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; a_1 &\equiv 1 \pmod 4\\[12pt]
\text{Using $(\text{eq}5),$}\;\,2a_2 + b_2 &=6\\[4pt]
\implies\; 0 + b_2 &\equiv 6 \pmod 8 
&&\text{[since $a_2 \equiv 0\,(\text{mod}\;4)$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;  b_2 &\equiv 6 \pmod 8\\[12pt]
\text{Using $(\text{eq}4),$}\;\,
2a_1 + b_1 + a_2b_2 &=4\\[4pt]
\implies\; 2 + b_1 &\equiv 4 \pmod 8 
&&\text{[since $a_1 \equiv 1\,(\text{mod}\;4)$,}\\[-1pt]
&&&\;\text{$a_2 \equiv 0\,(\text{mod}\;4)$,}\\[-1pt] 
&&&\;\text{and $b_2$ is even]}\\[-1pt]
\implies\;  b_1 &\equiv 2 \pmod 8\\[12pt]
\text{Using $(\text{eq}3),$}\;\,
3a_0 + a_1b_2 + a_2b_1 &= 5\\[4pt]
\implies\;  a_1b_2 + a_2b_1 &= 2
&&\text{[since $a_0=1$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;  a_1b_2&\equiv 2 \pmod 8
&&\text{[since $a_2 \equiv 0\,(\text{mod}\;4)$,}\\[-1pt]
&&&\;\text{and $b_1$ is even]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;  6a_1&\equiv 2 \pmod 8
&&\text{[since $b_2 \equiv 6\,(\text{mod}\;8)$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;  3a_1&\equiv 1 \pmod 4\\[4pt]
\implies\;  3 &\equiv 1 \pmod 4
&&\text{[since $a_1 \equiv 1\,(\text{mod}\;4)$]}\\[4pt]
\text{c}&\text{ontradiction}
\end{align*}

Therefore $f$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 3):

As others pointed out we can use modular factorization. I think that a quinella of modulo two and five gives us a winning betting slip with the least amount of paper-and-pencil work.

Modulo $2$ we have 
$$
f(x)\equiv x^3+x+1
$$
which is well known to be irreducible. Like quasi (+1) we conclude that if we have a factorization $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ then we must have $g(x)\equiv x^3+x+1$ and
$h(x)\equiv 1$. Here the leading coefficient of $h$ must be even, so $g$ must have an odd leading coefficient. Therefore $\deg g(x)=3=\deg h(x)$.

Let's look at it modulo $5$.
$$
f(x)\equiv2x^6+x^5-x^4-2x+1.
$$
We see that $f(-2)\equiv0\pmod5$ so in $\Bbb{Z}_5[x]$ $f$ is divisible by $(x+2)$. By polynomial division we get
$$
f(x)=2(x+2)(x^5+x^4-1)\in\Bbb{Z}_5[x].
$$
That degree five factor, denote it by $m(x)$, is actually irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_5[x]$. There are many ways to see this. The simplest may be 
to observe that the reciprocal of $m(x)$ is
$$
\tilde{m}(x)=x^5m(\frac1x)=-(x^5-x-1).
$$
This falls under the umbrella of Artin-Schreier polynomials. 
A standard exercise is to show that whenever $a\not\equiv 0\pmod p$, $p$ a prime, the polynomial
$$
x^p-x-a
$$
is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619) for a variety of arguments with varying degrees of sophistication proving this result. With $\tilde{m}(x)$ known to be irreducible we can conclude that $m(x)$ is irreducible also.

Anyway, with the knowledge that modulo five $f$ has an irreducible factor of degree five, we have run into a contradiction with the modulo two conclusion that the only possible factorization is the product of two cubics. Therefore $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: Doesn't $f\,\text{mod}\,3$ have a zero coefficient for the $x^5$ term?

Comment: Thanks @quasi. You're right. I must have miscopied the polynomial. Unfortunately that error ruins this approach. I don't fancy paper-and-pencil-proving that the remaining quintic factor, what I get with the correct version, is irreducible :-(

Comment: Thankfully my luck was in, and using modulo $5$ instead of $3$ saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Berlekamp algorithm for polynomials $f\in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$, we see that $f(x)$ is irreducible for $p=29, 31, 47$, etc., see Bemte's comment. Hence $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ has degree $6$ and assumes prime values for these $13 > 2 \cdot 6$ points and so must be irreducible: 
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
n & f(n) \\
2 & 431 \\
14 & 18453443 \\
17 & 57152981 \\
21 & 196861141 \\
30 & 1607175091 \\
39 & 7588383193 \\
89 & 1027721432693 \\
105 & 2757260165941 \\
122 & 6757665621431 \\
131 & 10340492467001 \\
161 & 35484310770581 \\
182 & 73889824920731 \\
201 & 133863373175221 \\
\end{array}
$$