# Prove that a polynomial of the form $x^p−x−a \in F[x]$ is either irreducible or splits in $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field with char$F = p$. Prove that a polynomial of the form $x^p−x−a \in F[x]$ is either irreducible or splits in $F$.

I've seen a few different ways of proving this with $x^p-a$. I know that $a \in F$ being a root of $F(x)$ means $a^p=a$, so $x^p−a=(x−a)^p$. But I don't think this property works for $x^p-x-a$.

Comment: Close to being a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619).

Answer (score 3):

This is an *Artin-Schreier* polynomial. If $\alpha$ is a root,
the other roots are $\alpha+k$ for $k\in\Bbb F_p$.
If $\alpha\notin F$ then for some nonzero $k\in\Bbb F_p$,
$\alpha+k$ is a conjugate of $\alpha$ over $F$. Then $\alpha+2k$
is a conjugate of $\alpha+k$ and so also a conjugate of $\alpha$, etc.
Then all $\alpha+mk$ are conjugates of $\alpha$, and these are all
the roots. Therefore $x^p-x-a$ is irreducible in this case.

Comment: So does it split when $a=0$? Because this seems to only work for $a$ nonzero?

Comment: Of course it splits when $a=0$, but also in other cases when $F\ne\Bbb F_p$. For instance, $X^2-X-1$ splits over $\Bbb F_4$.