# For $p$ prime, is the polynomial $x^p-x+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

It is possible, for $p\in\mathbb{N}$ prime, that the polynomial 
$x^p-x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

By the identity 
$a^p\equiv a$  mod $p$ for any $a\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ surely there is not a root for this polinomial.

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z_p = \mathbb Z/p$ or the $p$-adic integers?

Comment: Sorry, $Z_p=Z/pZ$

Comment: This is an Artin-Schreier polynomial. Google this. If it had a root then it completely splits (“one out, all out”).

Comment: Presumably the intended question was is this polynomial irreducible for all primes $p$?

Comment: Yes I want to prove what you said

Comment: Several approaches to proving this are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619). But, barto's method is nice (+1) even though variants of it are also in that "mother" thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always irreducible: by Little Fermat, if $f(x)$ is a monic irreducible factor, then so is $f(x+n)$ for all $n$. Let $k>0$ be minimal for which $f(x) = f(x+k)$. Then $k \mid p$, hence $k=1$ or $k=p$.

If $k=p$, we conclude that all $f(x+n)$ are distinct mod $p$ for $n=0,1,\ldots, p-1$. Hence $f$ has degree $1$. But $x^p-x+1$ has no roots, contradiction.

If $k=1$, $f(x)=f(x+1)$ hence $f(x)-f(0)$ has $p$ roots, so $f$ has degree $p$, and $x^p-x+1$ is irreducible.

---

By the exact same argument, we see that $x^p-x-\alpha$ is irreducible for $\alpha \neq 0$.