# Proof verification -- $x^p - x + a$ is irreducible over a field of characteristic $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and $a \in k$. Assume that the equation $x^p - x + a$ does not have any solutions in $k$. Show that the polynomial $x^p - x + a$ is irreducible over $k$.

Below is my proof of this:

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^p - x + a$, so that $\alpha^p - \alpha + a$ = 0. Then $(\alpha + 1)^p - (\alpha + 1) + a = \alpha^p + 1 - \alpha - 1 + a = \alpha^p - \alpha + a = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha + 1$ is a root of $x^p - x + a$. Thus, letting $\beta = \alpha + 1$, by the same logic as before, we would have that $\beta + 1 = \alpha +2$ is a root of $x^{p} - x + a$. Continuing inductively in this fashion, we see that we can obtain all $p$ roots of $x^p - x + a$ in this way $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha + i$ ($1 \leq i \leq p$) are roots of the polynomial $x^p - x + a$.

First, we note that, since $x^p - x + a$ does not have any solutions in $k$, $a \neq 0$, for if $a = 0$, the element $0 \in k$ would be a solution to $x^p - x + a$. Also, we see that $x^p - x + a$ is separable, since $\frac{d}{dx}(x^p - x + a) = px^{p-1} - 1 = 0 - 1 = -1 \neq 0$ (keeping in mind that we are in a field of characteristic $p$). Thus, letting the splitting field of $x^p - x + a$ over $k$ be denoted by $L$, we see that the finite algebraic field extension $L/k$ is normal and separable (where we've used that a finite field extension $F$ of a field $K$ is a finite normal extension of $F$ if $K$ is a separable splitting field over $F$) $\Rightarrow$ $L/k$ is a Galois extension. Thus, $|Aut(L/k)| = [L:k] = p$, where $[L:k] = p$ follows from the fact that if we obtain one root $\alpha$ of $x^p - x + a$, we obtain all $p$ roots of $x^p - x + a$ by the argument given in the last paragraph. Thus, the Galois group of $L$ over $k$ is of order $p$ $\Rightarrow$ the Galois group of $L$ over $k$ is cyclic of order $p$ $\Rightarrow$ the Galois group of $L$ over $k$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, is a transitive subgroup of $S_p$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^p - x + a$ is irreducible over $k$, where the final implication follows from Theorem 2.9 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisaspermgp.pdf.

I'm aware that this question has been asked multiple times on the network. But I'd like a verification of my proof provided above, using Galois theory. In particular, I'm worried that I've made too much of a jump in saying that the finite extension described is normal.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Many proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the comment. I'm aware of those proofs. I was just wondering about mine. (=

Comment: That's fine! I was just checking which of those proofs might be close to yours. And then missus called me to do some chores :-) May be zyx's proof is close to yours in that the key is the realization that the Galois group must be cyclic of order $p$.

Comment: But IMO you should be more detailed in how you conclude that there are $p$ automorphisms. The key is that *any* automorphism must be of the form $\alpha\mapsto \alpha+i$ for some $i=1,2,\ldots,p-1$. *And any such automorphism is of order $p$.* Counting the roots does not suffice. For example the zeros of $(x^2-2)(x^2-8)$ are clearly all of the form $n\sqrt2$ with integer $n$, so adjoining one of those roots gives you all four. This does not imply that there would be four automorphisms.

Comment: So: 1) $\alpha$ is not in $k$. 2) With $\alpha$ we get the other roots $\alpha+i$, so $L=k(\alpha)$ is the splitting field. 3) Separability implies $L/k$ is Galois of degree $>1$. 4) A non-identity $k$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ must come from $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha+i$, $0<i<p$. 5) $\sigma$ has order $p$. 6) $Aut(L/k)$ acts transitively on the set of roots. 7) it is irreducible. Compressing some steps is possible. But I'm a bit worried about the potential for circularity in your argument. The fact that $L$ is a splitting field doesn't imply $[L:k]=p$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see. Thanks a lot for your comments. I do agree that I should be more careful about showing there are $p$ automorphisms. I appreciate your time. (=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is essentially the same as the argument in the first paragraph of the proof of Theorem 5.10 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/linearchar.pdf), except more attention is given there to explaining why the field extension $L/k$ (your notation) has degree $p$, along the lines of what Jyrki Lahtonen is saying in the comments above. The "jump" in your proof is not in explaining why $L/k$ is normal (a splitting field over $k$ of a polynomial in $k[x]$ is a normal extension), but in explaining why $[L:k] = p$ since when you don't (yet) know the polynomial $x^p-x+a$ is *irreducible* you can't be sure that adjoining a root of it to $k$ will give you an extension of degree equal to $p$.