# $x^5-x-3$ galois group over $\mathbb{F}_5$?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

How can I find the Galois group of $x^5-x-3$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you briefly mentioned your attempts so far. To start how does the polynomial factor over $\mathbb{F}_5$?

Comment: It's an Artin-Schreier polynomial, so clearly irreducible.

Comment: Furthermore, the Wiki page says that if $\beta$ is a root,so are $\beta+i$, $1 \leq i \leq p$, so the splitting field is $\mathbb F_5(\beta)$. It doesn't give the details, but you can try using Fermat's little theorem to show this.

Comment: Several proofs of irreducibility [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P=x^5-x-3$, the polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_5$.

For any $a\in \mathbb{F}_5$ we have $a^5=a\neq a+3$, so $a$ is not a root of $P$.  If we attach a single root $\beta$ of $P$, we obtain a finite extension $\mathbb{F}_5[\beta]$, of degree $2,3$ or $5$, depending on whether or not the polynomial is irreducible.  Let $F:\mathbb{F}_5[\beta]\to \mathbb{F}_5[\beta]$ denote the Frobenius automorphism, sending $\alpha\mapsto \alpha^5$.

Now for $a\in \mathbb{F}_5$ we have that $F(\beta+a)=F(\beta)+F(a)=F(\beta)+a$.  Thus $$(\beta+a)^5-(\beta+a)-3=\beta^5-\beta-3+a-a=0.$$

Thus we know $P$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_5[\beta]$.  Further, if $P$ were not irreducible it would have a quadratic factor with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_5$.  However:$$(x-\beta-a_1)(x-\beta-a_2)=x^2-(2\beta+a_1+a_2)x+(\beta-a_1)(\beta-a_2)$$
and $2\beta+a_1+a_2\notin \mathbb{F}_5$ for any $a_1,a_2\in \mathbb{F}_5$.

We conclude that $P$ is irreducible and has a splitting field $\mathbb{F}_5[\beta]$ of degree $5$.

Its Galois group is therefore generated by $F$ which has order $5$ (that is $\alpha^{5^5}=\alpha\alpha^{5^5-1}=\alpha\alpha^{|\mathbb{F}_5[\beta]^*|}=\alpha$, for every $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}_5[\beta]$).  We conclude that the Galois group is $C_5$.

Comment: A slicker argument would be to say that if $P$ factorised, then attaching a root of one irreducible factor would give you a splitting field for any other irreducible factor, so all irreducible factors have the same degree and the degrees add up to $5$.  However $5$ is prime.