# A question regarding existence of Cyclic extension ( pg 296 Question 6)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Consider the following problem:  from algebra by Thomas Hungerford Section 5.

If char $K = p \neq $0, let $K_p = ${ $u^p - u | u\in K$ }
then show that  a cyclic extension field F of K of degree p exists if and only if $K \neq K_p$ .

Let K $\neq K_p$ , but I couldn't make any progress on this side.

Now, for the opposite, it is given that  Cyclic extension exists and let K =$K_p$ , so $u^p - u=u$ and I obtained a contradiction taht the polynomial is neither irreducible nor separable.

But I need help for the converse part.

Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Let $K\ne K_p$ and $a\in K\setminus K_p$, i.e. the polynomial $f=x^p-x-a$ has no roots in $K$. By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81583/how-do-i-prove-that-xp-xa-is-irreducible-in-a-field-with-p-elements-when/458663#458663) $f$ is irreducible. Let $L=K(u)$ where $u$ is a zero of $f$ in some extension field. A straightforward computation shows that $u+r$ for $r\in\Bbb F_p$ (the prime field) are also zeros of $f$ (or just see the linked answer again). It follows that $L/K$ is Galois and that the Galois group is generated by $u\mapsto u+1$, i.e. it is cyclic.

Comment: Can you please tell why K is a bigger set than $K_p$?

Comment: 1 Can you please reply to my comment above?

Comment: Can you please reply to my above comment if you have some time to spare? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that the original question is asking: If $K\ne K_p$, then $K$ has a cyclic extension of degree $p$. So I am assuming that $K\ne K_p$.