# How to know if this polynomial is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I've been working on this problem and I'm stuck on this part, I need to factorize this polynomial in the field of integers modulo 5

$f(x)=(x^5-x)^2-1$

And so far I've gotten that by difference of squares that it can be factored into
$$f(x)=(x^5-x-1)(x^5-x+1)$$

However from here I cannot really tell for sure this two polynomials are irreducible, I  know (Because of the solution that they are), but I can't justify it, I've thought of trying to use Eisenstein but it's not applicable and there are too many irreducible polynomials to try them out one by one

Is there something I'm missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A reducible polynomial of degree 5 must have a linear or quadratic factor. Check both these options.

Comment: I'm sorry but why only those two factors? Couldn't I also reduce it in one polynomial of degree 3 and other of degree 2?

Comment: Degree 2 factor is what I call a quadratic factor.

Comment: So what I should do is try polynomials and see that i can't divide them?

Comment: Clearly there are no linear factors . There are, I think, $10$ irreducible quadratics mod $5$. Not far too many to try, but tedious. Perhaps easier would be to crunch through the euclidean algorithm and see whether $hcf(x^5 - x -1, x^{25}-x)$ is non-trivial, not more than half an hour's work.

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/72031 and let me know if your question can be closed as a duplicate of this.