# Showing that $f=X^p-X+T$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p(T)[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, rational-functions

Let $K=\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ be the field of rational functions on one variable T over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and $f=X^p-X+T \in K[X]$. I want to show that $f$ is an irreducible polynomial.

I know that $T$ is a prime element in the field $K$, so I’m trying to apply Eisenstein criterion for that element. The only point where I was having some doubts is verifying that $T$ divides $-1$, but I think that is true since $-1/T \in K$. Is that right?

**Edit**: As discussed in the comments, Eisenstein’s criterion can’t be applied here. I don’t really see how to apply [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/81590/1002163) here though, since $T \notin \mathbb{F}_p$, so $T^p \neq T$ as far as I know…

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion applied to $T$ won't do since the middle coefficient isn't divisible by $T$.

Comment: @hunter Oh I see, do you have any hints on what other irreducibility criteria could I look for?

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81583/how-do-i-prove-that-xp-xa-is-irreducible-in-a-field-with-p-elements-when

Comment: @Crostul That's some excellent answers! The first one works also in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{F}_p[T]$ is a UFD, $f$ is irreducible in $K[X]$ $\iff$ $f$ is prime in $\mathbb{F}_p[T][X]=\mathbb{F}_p[X][T]$.  On the other hand, $\mathbb{F}_p[X][T]/(f)=\mathbb{F}_p[X]$, an integral domain.

Comment: Is $f$ irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[T]$ equivalent to $f$ irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$? Also, why $\mathbb{F}_p[X][T]/(f)=\mathbb{F}_p[X]$?

Comment: @Gokimo For the first question, yes. See [2.0.4] of https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/12.pdf for example. For the second, we have for any ring $R$ and any element $a\in R$ an isomorphism $R[T]/(T-a)\simeq R$ induced by $T\mapsto a$. In my answer, $a=-X^p+X$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of an *additive* analogue in characteristic $p$ of the following multiplicative theorem about binomial polynomials.

**Theorem**. *For a field $K$ and $a \in K^\times$, $x^p - a$ is reducible in $K[x]$ if and only if this polynomial has a root in $K$.*

*Proof*:  See Theorem 3.1 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/simpleradical.pdf).

**Theorem**.  *For a field $K$ of characteristic $p$ and $a \in K$, $x^p - x - a$ is reducible in $K[x]$ if and only if this polynomial has a root in $K$.*

*Proof*:  Exercise.  Mimic the proof of the previous theorem using additive ideas in place of multiplicative ones (e.g., the roots of $x^p - x - a$ in terms of one root $r$ are $r + c$ for $c \in \mathbf F_p$).

**Example**.  Consider $x^p - x + T$ in $K[x]$ where $K = \mathbf F_p(T)$.
To show it is irreducible, by the second theorem with $a = -T$ it suffices to show this polynomial has no root in $K$.  Do this as follows.

Step 1: Show that an element of $\mathbf F_p(T)$ that is a root of $x^p-x+T$ has to be in $\mathbf F_p[T]$ and can't be constant.

Step 2: By counting degrees, show a nonconstant polynomial in $\mathbf F_p[T]$ is not a root of $x^p - x + T$.