# $E=F[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^p-x-c$.

Tags: finite-groups, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$, and let $E/F$ be a Galois extension with cyclic galois group $\langle \sigma \rangle$ of order $p$.

I want to prove that $E=F(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ of the form $x^p-x-c$. I know that this polynomial is irreducible if and only it don't has roots on F. Any idea about how I can prove this?

It is an exercice of Rotman, Galois theory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [So-called Artin-Schreier Extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752410/so-called-artin-schreier-extension). Even if it doesn't, the keyword "Artin-Schreier Extension" will definitely be helpful ^_^

Comment: Yes, thankss :)