# Galois Group of $x^p-x+a$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for prime $p$ and $a\neq 0\in \mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Question is to find Galois group of $f(x)=x^p-x+a$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$  for prime $p$ and $a\neq 0\in \mathbb{F}_p$

What i have done so far is :

I could see that $f(x)$ is Irreducible and separable...

Now, I need to find splitting field of $f(x)$

Suppose $b$ is a root of $f(x)$ in some extension field $E$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$

i.e., $b^p-b+a=0$

Consider $f(b+1)=(b+1)^p-(b+1)+a=b^p+1-b-1+a=b^p-b+a=0$

So, for similar reasons $f(b+i)$ is root..

So, if i adjoin one root then it would automatically contain all roots..

So, splitting field of $f(x)$ would be $\mathbb{F}_p(b)$

Now there is some little gap..

I would like to say that as $\mathbb{F}_p(b)$ is just a finite extension we see $\mathbb{F}_p(b)=\mathbb{F}_{p^p}$

We know that Galois group of finite extension is cyclic ...

In this case we see that Galois group is generated by $\sigma$ defined as $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha^p$

I just want to make sure there are no Gaps in this..

Please help me to make this perfect...

Comment: Looks good to me. For a little bit of extra knowledge [here's a proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/50062/11619) of the standard fact that in characteristic $p$ all cyclic Galois extensions of degree $p$ are splitting fields of polynomials like this.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen :  Oh.. Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe worth to know, the polynomial your are studying is so-called Artin-Schreier, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory

Comment: @NickyHekster : Yes Yes.. thank you :)

Comment: @Praphulla - I don't see what it has to do with you posting on this page. Concerning this, $\zeta+\zeta^5$ has degree 6 over $\mathbb{Q}$. So your minimum polynomial is not the one you were alluding to.

Comment: @NickyHekster : Sorry to bother you... I got it.. thank you :)

Comment: @Praphulla - not at all, I have not posted my calculations since others were before me finding the minimum polynomial of $\zeta+\zeta^5$.