# Galois group of a Schreier solvable polynomial is solvable

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

I came across this problem which I couldn't solve thus far:

> **Definition** Let $F_0$ be a field with $char(F)=p>0$. A polynomial $f \in F_0[X]$ is said to be Schreier solvable if there exists a series of extensions $F_i/F_{i-1}, \, F_i=F_{i-1}[\alpha_i], \, i=1,...,r$, such that $\alpha_i$ is a root of a polynomial  $X^p-X-a_i \in F_{i-1}[X]$ and $f$ splits in $F_r$.
>
> Show that a Galois group of a Schreier solvable polynomial is a solvable group.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You have a tower of Artin-Schreier extensions (adjoining a root of
$X^p-X-a$). An Artin-Schreier extension is Galois with a trivial or
a cyclic order $p$ group. So a tower of Artin-Schreier extensions
will have a Galois group a $p$-group. Each $p$-group is soluble...

Comment: I'm not familiar yet with Artin-Schreier extensions, only started to read about it following your comment. Could it be solved without it? 
Also, do you have a reference for the fact that an Artin-Schreier extension is Galois with a trivial or a cyclic order $p$-group?

Comment: @Brassican In some sense the answer is yes, since Artin-Schreier extensions are a special case of the result you seek. Any big book on Galois theory will do Artin-Schreier extensions; I'm sure that Lang's *Algebra" has it.

Comment: @Brassican If $\alpha_i\notin F_{i-1}$, then $x^p-x-a_i$ is irreducible over $F_{i-1}$, and the Galois group is generated by $\alpha_i\mapsto\alpha_i+1$. The fun fact is that **any** Galois extension of degree $p$ of char $p$ fields has that form. As Lord Shark (+1) said this is very much textbook stuff. Yet, these bits have been covered on our site as well. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619) for the irreducibility result and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50041/11619) for the other result.