# Any cyclic extension over fields with characteristic $p$ with degree $p$ that it is the splitting field of a polynomial of the form $X^p-X-a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I found this statement in [Milne's *Fields and Galois Theory*](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf) (page 72):

[image]

More precisely, it is the last line I would like to prove. Could someone help me to prove that question?

I understood everything before the last sentence but now I don't know how to approach this problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take the proof of the equivalent fact for $x^n-a$ and replace the multiplicative hilbert theorem 90 with the additive one and the norm with the trace. Instead of roots of unity, you'll use $\alpha + i$ for $i=1,...,p$ (which is the obstacle to generalizing to higher degree). This result is VI.6.4 in Lang.

Comment: Artin–Schreier theory

Comment: What Touken Toucan and rain1 said. For what it's worth, I outlined "the book argument" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50062/11619). Surely the authors of text books have done a better job.

Comment: This is proved here https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09I7